# How to hack fan control speed?

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, uefi

So I recently bought a new laptop (Acer Aspire A315-57g) on which I found that the cooling solution wasn't optimal, and I decided that I want more RPMs from my fan. However, I wasn't able to find a working software that is able to max it out.

So I have IDA on my disposal, I have Win32, C, C++, x86/-64 asm knowledge - Visual Studio 2022 Preview with C++ workload installed - where do I begin?

I tried numeral hacks (involving installing Acer gaming laptop tuning tool Predator control or something with simple WMI spoof), enabling "Cool Boost" in the registry for Quick Access, I tried Fan Control app from GitHub with different configs. Nothing budged though - the best I got is the rpm meter (in the Acer Predator control).

Comment: Are you sure that the software isn't maxing the fans out already? I wouldn't hack anything here since you might kill your inbuilt fans or something more expensive. I'd buy a laptop stand, perhaps one that comes with fans or one where you can install some yourself. They improve airflow by themselves, too

Comment: when i updated bios i noticed, that fan speed became thee times faster than it was on 100%. So direct acces to controller may help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX7GHqq28uU&pp=ygUYc21hbGxlc3QgYmxkYyBjb250cm9sbGVy